# How do you remove the intersection curve between two translucent surfaces

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting two surfaces using `surf` and the `FaceAlpha` parameter. When `FaceAlpha` is less than 1, the surfaces are translucent and the curve of intersection shows up in white. Why does this happen, and how do you remove it?

[image]

Code to reproduce in 2015b:

```
x = linspace(0, 1, 21);
y = linspace(0, 1, 21);
[x, y] = meshgrid(x, y);
z1 = x;
z2 = y;
hold off
surf(x, y, z1, 'FaceAlpha', 0.2)
hold on
surf(x, y, z2, 'FaceAlpha', 0.2)
```

Contrast this with:

```
hold off
surf(x, y, z1)
hold on
surf(x, y, z2)
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with OpenGL. With `set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters')` the white line disappears.

Comment: that works perfectly. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with OpenGL. Change the renderer to `painters` and the white line disappears:

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters')
```

(tested on Mac OS 10.11.1 and MATLAB 2015b)